# Salesforce SOAP API for ApexJobs

Tags: salesforce

I am looking for SOAP API for Salesforce to get the list of all ApexJobs,

I have used the following API for login.
Request type: POST
Request URL: https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/
body(XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
      <n1:username>username</n1:username>
      <n1:password>password+security token</n1:password>
    </n1:login>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Response:
MetaServiceUrl, SessionId, OrgId, UserId etc.

Now, which API should I use to get the list of ApexJobs & what should be present in body?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read session id and the url to use from now on from the response.

Subsequent requests must be sent to what you got back (or you can hardcode `mycompany--mysandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce.com` as the endpoint but then you must remember to change it every time you deploy your app... It's more work to read it from the response but it pays off)

Then it becomes just a normal query like on any other table?
If you / your admin are happy with running this in say developer console

```soql
SELECT ApexClass.Name, CreatedDate, CompletedDate, Status, ExtendedStatus
FROM AsyncApexJob
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

then all you need is

```xml
POST https://mycompany--mysandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/59.0 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 649
Host: mycompany--mysandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D... session id goes here. It'll start with 00D and have ! in it</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:query>
         <urn:queryString>
SELECT ApexClass.Name, CreatedDate, CompletedDate, Status, ExtendedStatus
FROM AsyncApexJob
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
LIMIT 10
</urn:queryString>
      </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response will be bit like

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader>
         <limitInfo>
            <current>12038</current>
            <limit>19920000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
         </limitInfo>
      </LimitInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <queryResponse>
         <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
            <done>true</done>
            <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
            <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
               <sf:type>AsyncApexJob</sf:type>
               <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
               <sf:ApexClass xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                  <sf:type>ApexClass</sf:type>
                  <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <sf:Name>Redacted</sf:Name>
               </sf:ApexClass>
               <sf:CreatedDate>2023-12-14T21:10:34.000Z</sf:CreatedDate>
               <sf:CompletedDate>2023-12-14T21:10:41.000Z</sf:CompletedDate>
               <sf:Status>Completed</sf:Status>
               <sf:ExtendedStatus xsi:nil="true"/>
            </records>
            <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
               <sf:type>AsyncApexJob</sf:type>
               <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
               <sf:ApexClass xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                  <sf:type>ApexClass</sf:type>
                  <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <sf:Name>Redacted</sf:Name>
               </sf:ApexClass>
               <sf:CreatedDate>2023-12-14T21:10:17.000Z</sf:CreatedDate>
               <sf:CompletedDate>2023-12-14T21:10:34.000Z</sf:CompletedDate>
               <sf:Status>Completed</sf:Status>
               <sf:ExtendedStatus xsi:nil="true"/>
            </records>
            (...)
            <size>10</size>
         </result>
      </queryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Really you wouldn't hand-craft it like that, you'd "consume" the WSDL file to use in your programming language of choice. Or there are even libraries that wrap most of it for you in C#, Java, PHP, Python... But if you want to hand-craft - something like this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, It worked well. But is there some SOQL query to get Session settings and Password policies details?

Comment: Don't think this is exposed to normal API queries. https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfxSUAR/allow-salesforce-api-to-fetch-the-password-policies-enabled-at-profile-level Could try asking on dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com? I know you can fetch them with metadata API (what's used for deployments for example): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilesessionsetting.htm

Comment: Can you let me know the API URL, request, and response?

Comment: Setup -> API -> download "metadata wsdl" and then you'd have to read up a bit about "package.xml" (if you have a salesforce dev in the team they should be familiar with it), answers like https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/369716/799

Answer (score 0):

Edit your template so it contains your username and password token and save the file as /tmp/login.txt. Then:

curl -s https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/51.0 -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" -H "SOAPAction: login" -d @/tmp/login.txt

Capture the SessionID. Then:

curl -o /tmp/FOController.exists.json -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D8F0000004kxV!AQ8AQIZlziGQIK91oP3SaX6iqcSNDT1IAT9g3j7Yqv0jHjMxc8_331QjqbcNgkcOV_k_MoYlHDz7pxxhEh7Eod8tioz8jjyy" [https://my--org.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Name+from+ApexClass+where+Name=\'FOController\';](https://my--org.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Name+from+ApexClass+where+Name=%5C%27FOController%5C%27;)

Comment: Your 2nd request is REST, not SOAP? And bold of you to publish session IDs to the world :/ even if that session is expired now people can take the org id out of it and try sending spam via web to case for example. Ugh

Comment: it's a fake sessionID, a fake org. and a fake class. Good luck with that.